# Defining an array in play's config file

Tags: scala, playframework, config, playframework-2.2

I didn't find any information about that topic. Is there any way to define an array in the standard play config file `app.config` which have such the values as?

```
application.secret="Gk<9kCgMu@A62eyfcJ;YZ2nFnA;4324/gfdg]afdsfds"
application.langs="en"
application.global=common.Global
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and described in the [Play configuration chapter](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Configuration).

In general, what you are looking for is this:

```
my.setting="[value1,value2,value3]"
```

In your code you can access it like this:

```
Play.current.configuration.getStringList("my.setting") //returns an Option[java.util.List[String]]
```

You may also use `getLongList`, `getBooleanList` and so on.

Comment: can we have list concatenation in config file itself?

Answer (score 0):

I find this answer searching for "play framework config array".

For Play 2.7 the correct syntax for a List is:

```
my.setting=["value1","value2","value3"]
```

otherwise you get an Exception like

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: application.conf @ file:/xxxxx/application.conf: 12:  my.setting has type STRING rather than LIST
```

Hope this helps someone else.